# When logged in as a user, the cart does not clear after completing the transaction via paypal in my Django project. It works when not logged in

Tags: javascript, python, django, paypal, e-commerce

I recently completed a YouTube tutorial series from Dennis Ivy on building a Django-based [ecommerce website](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ELCMngbM0E&list=PL-51WBLyFTg0omnamUjL1TCVov7yDTRng). My website works except for 1 major bug. When the user is logged in and goes through the checkout process, the cart does not clear after completing the paypal checkout. When the user is not logged in ("AnonymousUser"), it works correctly. I'm struggling to find the source of this bug. Any suggestions? I'm including the parts of the code I think might be relevant.

**cart.js**

```
var updateBtns = document.getElementsByClassName('update-cart')

for (i = 0; i < updateBtns.length; i++) {
    updateBtns[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
        var productId = this.dataset.product
        var action = this.dataset.action
        console.log('productId:', productId, 'Action:', action)
        console.log('USER:', user)

        if (user == 'AnonymousUser'){
            addCookieItem(productId, action)
        }else{
            updateUserOrder(productId, action)
        }
    })
}

function updateUserOrder(productId, action){
    console.log('User is authenticated, sending data...')

        var url = '/update_item/'

        fetch(url, {
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
            }, 
            body:JSON.stringify({'productId':productId, 'action':action})
        })
        .then((response) => {
           return response.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
            location.reload()
        });
}

function addCookieItem(productId, action){
    console.log('User is not authenticated')

    if (action == 'add'){
        if (cart[productId] == undefined){
        cart[productId] = {'quantity':1}

        }else{
            cart[productId]['quantity'] += 1
        }
    }

    if (action == 'remove'){
        cart[productId]['quantity'] -= 1

        if (cart[productId]['quantity'] <= 0){
            console.log('Item should be deleted')
            delete cart[productId];
        }
    }
    console.log('CART:', cart)
    document.cookie ='cart=' + JSON.stringify(cart) + ";domain=;path=/"
    
    location.reload()
}

function updateUserOrder(productId, action){
    console.log('User is logged in, sending data...')

    var url = '/update_item/'

    fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type':'application/json',
            "X-CSRFToken": csrftoken,
        },
        body:JSON.stringify({'productId': productId, 'action':action})
    })

    .then((response) => {
        if (!response.ok) {
            // error processing
            throw 'Error';
        }
        return response.json()
    })

    .then((data) => {
        console.log('data:', data)
        location.reload()
    });

}
```

**checkout.html**

```
{% extends 'store/main.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="box-element" id="form-wrapper">
                <form id="form">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    <div id="user-info">
                        <div class="form-field">
                            <input required class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name..">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-field">
                            <input required class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email..">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div id="shipping-info">
                        <hr>
                        <p>Shipping Information:</p>
                        <hr>
                        <div class="form-field">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address..">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-field">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="city" placeholder="City..">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-field">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="state" placeholder="State..">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-field">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="zipcode" placeholder="Zip code..">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <input id="form-button" class="btn btn-success btn-block" type="submit" value="Continue">
                </form>

            </div>
            <br>

            <div class="box-element hidden" id="payment-info">
                <small>Paypal Options</small>
                <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>
            <!--    <button id="make-payment">Make Payment</button>-->
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="box-element">
                <a class="btn btn-outline-dark" href="{% url 'cart' %}">&#x2190;Back to Cart</a>
                <hr>
                <h3>Order Summary</h3>
                </hr>
                {% for item in items %}
                <div class="cart-row">
                    <div style="flex:2"><img class="row-image" src="{{item.product.imageURL}}"></div>
                    <div style="flex:2"><p>{{item.product.name}}</p></div>
                    <div style="flex:1"><p>${{item.product.price|floatformat:2}}</p></div>
                    <div style="flex:1"><p>x{{item.quantity}}</p></div>
                </div>

                {% endfor %}

                <h5>Items:   {{order.get_cart_items}}</h5>
                <h5>Total:   ${{order.get_cart_total|floatformat:2}}</h5>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=AXGaPHyuQWZKVOsyxDeiZQmOzqL9893AN4B4P6hz3E77jot-l5UXru7WG6zcxNJ48xtfAsRCUNlfkYGt&currency=USD&disable-funding=credit"></script>

<script>
    var total = '{{order.get_cart_total}}'
    // Render the PayPal button into #paypal-button-container
    paypal.Buttons({

        style:{
            color:'blue',
            shape:'rect',
        },

        // Set up the transaction
        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                    amount: {
                        value: parseFloat(total).toFixed(2)
                    }
                }]
            });
        },

        // Finalize the transaction
        onApprove: function(data, actions) {
            return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {
                // Successful capture! For demo purposes:
                submitFormData()
            

                // Replace the above to show a success message within this page, e.g.
                // const element = document.getElementById('paypal-button-container');
                // element.innerHTML = '';
                // element.innerHTML = '<h3>Thank you for your payment!</h3>';
                // Or go to another URL:  actions.redirect('thank_you.html');
            });
        }


    }).render('#paypal-button-container');
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var shipping = '{{order.shipping}}'


    if(shipping == "False"){
        document.getElementById("shipping-info").innerHTML = ''
    }

    if (user != 'AnonymousUser'){
        document.getElementById('user-info').innerHTML = ''
    }

    if (shipping == "False" && user != 'AnonymousUser'){
        //hide entire form if user is logged in and shpping is false
        document.getElementById('form-wrapper').classList.add("hidden");
        //show payment if logged in user wants to buy an item that does not require shipping
        document.getElementById('payment-info').classList.remove("hidden");
    }

    var form = document.getElementById('form')

    csrftoken = form.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value
    console.log('Newtoken:', form.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value)

    form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log('Form Submitted...')
        document.getElementById('form-button').classList.add("hidden");
        document.getElementById('payment-info').classList.remove("hidden");
    })
/*
    document.getElementById('make-payment').addEventListener('click', function(e){
        submitFormData()
    })
*/
    function submitFormData(){
        console.log('Payment button clicked')
        
        var userFormData = {
            'name':null,
            'email':null,
            'total':total,
        }

        var shippingInfo = {
            'address':null,
            'city':null,
            'state':null,
            'zipcode':null,
        }

        if(shipping != 'False'){
            shippingInfo.address = form.address.value
            shippingInfo.city = form.city.value
            shippingInfo.state = form.state.value
            shippingInfo.zipcode = form.zipcode.value

        }

        if(user == 'AnonymousUser'){
            userFormData.name = form.name.value
            userFormData.email = form.email.value

        }

        var url = '/process_order/'

        fetch(url,{
            method:'POST',
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,

            },
            body:JSON.stringify({'form':userFormData, 'shipping':shippingInfo})
        })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            console.log('Success:', data);
            alert('Transaction completed');

            cart = {}
            document.cookie = 'cart=' + JSON.stringify(cart) + ";domain=;path=/"

            window.location.href = "{% url 'store' %}"
        })

    }

</script>

{% endblock content %}
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import JsonResponse
import datetime
import json

from .models import *
from .utils import cookieCart, cartData, guestOrder

# Create your views here.
def store(request):
    data = cartData(request)
    
    cartItems = data['cartItems']
    order = data['order']
    items = data['items']

    products = Product.objects.all()
    context = {'products':products, 'cartItems': cartItems}
    return render(request, 'store/store.html', context)

def cart(request):
    data = cartData(request)

    cartItems = data['cartItems']
    order = data['order']
    items = data['items']

    context = {'items':items, 'order':order, 'cartItems': cartItems, 'shipping':False}
    return render(request, 'store/cart.html', context)

def checkout(request):
    data = cartData(request)
    
    cartItems = data['cartItems']
    order = data['order']
    items = data['items']

    context = {'items':items, 'order':order, 'cartItems': cartItems, 'shipping':False}
    return render(request, 'store/checkout.html', context)

def updateItem(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    productId = data['productId']
    action = data['action']

    print('Action:', action)
    print('productId:', productId)

    customer = request.user.customer
    product = Product.objects.get(id=productId)
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)

    orderItem, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(order=order, product=product)

    if action == 'add':
        orderItem.quantity = (orderItem.quantity + 1)
    elif action == 'remove':
        orderItem.quantity = (orderItem.quantity - 1)

    orderItem.save()

    if orderItem.quantity <= 0:
        orderItem.delete()

    return JsonResponse('Item was added', safe=False)

def processOrder(request):
    transaction_id = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
    data = json.loads(request.body)

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)

    else:
        customer, order = guestOrder(request, data)

    total = float(data['form']['total'])
    order.transaction_id = transaction_id

    if total == order.get_cart_total:
        order.complete = True
    order.save()

    if order.shipping == True:
        ShippingAddress.objects.create(
            customer=customer,
            order=order,
            address=data['shipping']['address'],
            city=data['shipping']['city'],
            state=data['shipping']['state'],
            zipcode=data['shipping']['zipcode'],
        )

    return JsonResponse('Payment complete!', safe=False)
```

**utils.py**

```
import json
from . models import *

def cookieCart(request):
    try:
        cart = json.loads(request.COOKIES['cart'])
    except:
            cart = {}

    print('Cart:', cart)
    items = []
    order = {'get_cart_total':0, 'get_cart_items':0}
    cartItems = order['get_cart_items']

    for i in cart:
        try:
            cartItems += cart[i]["quantity"]

            product = Product.objects.get(id=i)
            total = (product.price * cart[i]['quantity'])

            order['get_cart_total'] += total
            order['get_cart_items'] += cart[i]['quantity']

            item = {
                    'product':{
                        'id':product.id,
                        'name':product.name,
                        'price':product.price,
                        'imageURL':product.imageURL,
                        },
                    'quantity':cart[i]['quantity'],
                    'get_total':total
                    }
            items.append(item)

            if product.digital == False:
                order['shipping'] = True
        except:
            pass
    return {'cartItems':cartItems, 'order':order, 'items':items}

def cartData(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
        cartItems = order.get_cart_items
    else:
        cookieData = cookieCart(request)
        cartItems = cookieData['cartItems']
        order = cookieData['order']
        items = cookieData['items']
    return {'cartItems':cartItems, 'order':order, 'items':items}

def guestOrder(request, data):
    print("User is not logged in...")
        
    print('Cookies:', request.COOKIES)
    name = data['form']['name']
    email = data['form']['email']

    cookieData = cookieCart(request)
    items = cookieData['items']

    customer, created = Customer.objects.get_or_create(
        email=email,
        )
    customer.name = name
    customer.save()

    order = Order.objects.create(
        customer=customer,
        complete=False
    )

    for item in items:
        product = Product.objects.get(id=item['product']['id'])

        orderItem = OrderItem.objects.create(
            product = product,
            order=order,
            quantity=item['quantity']
        )
    return customer, order
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I fixed it. The price field in the product model was a DecimalField so the total from the front end was not matching the total from the back end. I did the following and it seems to be working.

```
def processOrder(request):
    transaction_id = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()
    data = json.loads(request.body)

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)

    else:
        customer, order = guestOrder(request, data)

    total = float(data['form']['total'])
    order.transaction_id = transaction_id
```

#THIS IS HOW I FIXED IT##

```
    orderFL = float(order.get_cart_total) #the solution

    if total == orderFL:
        order.complete = True
    order.save()

    if order.shipping == True:
        ShippingAddress.objects.create(
            customer=customer,
            order=order,
            address=data['shipping']['address'],
            city=data['shipping']['city'],
            state=data['shipping']['state'],
            zipcode=data['shipping']['zipcode'],
        )

    return JsonResponse('Payment complete!', safe=False)
```